# Is Dr. Drago's Madcap Chase / Die Total Verrückte Rallye playable on current systems?

Tags: pc, backwards-compatibility, dr-dragos-madcap-chase

[Dr. Drago's Madcap Chase](http://www.mobygames.com/game/dr-dragos-madcap-chase) (from German studio Blue Byte, orig. title "*Die total verrückte Rallye*") was released in 1995. I remember it crashing too often to be playable under Windows XP even in Dosbox.

It seems this game never was famous outside of Germany, so neither *Good Old Games* nor *Steam*, usually my first two places when looking for older games that are playable today, are offering it.

I haven't tested on Win7/8 or with current emulation methods (dosbox/vm/...), so my question is:
Is there a way to play the game on a current system?

I'm willing to grab a remake if this is the only way possible.

*Picture for reminder purposes:*
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my attempts at testing it, you may have some success with a Win95/98 VM - don't forget to set the screen to 256 colors.

DOSbox won't run this, and Wine fails pretty miserably in OS X because of the missing 16-bit support (if installed via homebrew).

UPDATE 10th December 2016: if you have OS X 10.11 or 10.12, you can run it directly in Wine without any hassles :)

Answer (score 0):

i can get it running in dosbox running an image of windows 95 but it's only 16 bit colour

it used to work in windows xp as far as i can remember just had a mouse issue where if you moved the mouse it would crash

unsure of an easy way to be able to play it

Comment: Use Windows 3.11 not 95